# php turn this syntax into object/array

Tags: php, arrays, string, object, decode

Is there a way of turning this:

```
network={
    ssid="tele2-ssid-66577"
    #psk="testtest2"
    psk=8308d8e34c60fe471fda6837ab5821694e8cf51a655f24295797df33d02df6e9
}
```

into an object or an array with php?

I tried json_decode with no result.

------------- UPDATE:

the end goal is to extract only the psk key, I just thought turning it into an object/array would be the easiest thing to do rather than meddling with regular expressions or fiddling with the string, but maybe it's not possible...

Comment: How and from where do you get this?

Comment: by generating a passphrase from terminal command

Comment: is this string with EOLs ?

Comment: I believe so, running exec() will only return the character of the very last line ie } so shell_exec was necessary to retrieve the whole thing

Comment: I have build a method that takes JSON value to parameter, that could you take the parameters and put them in Array is that  a way to GO? So I can give you link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it through regex and then some processing

```
$str = 'network={
    ssid="tele2-ssid-66577"
    #psk="testtest2"
    psk=8308d8e34c60fe471fda6837ab5821694e8cf51a655f24295797df33d02df6e9
}';

$output = array();
if (preg_match_all('/(([^=]+)=\{|\s+([^#]+)=(.*))/', $str, $match) and sizeof($match[2]) > 2) {
    $output[$match[2][0]] = array();
    for ($i=1; $i<sizeof($match[2]); $i++) {
        $key = trim($match[3][$i]);
        $value = trim($match[4][$i]);

        // remove outer double quotes
        if (preg_match('/^"(.*)"$/', $value, $match2)) $value = $match2[1];

        // save
        $output[$match[2][0]][$key] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Giving the output:

```
Array
(
    [network] => Array
        (
            [ssid] => tele2-ssid-66577
            [psk] => 8308d8e34c60fe471fda6837ab5821694e8cf51a655f24295797df33d02df6e9
        )
)
```